# Merge multiple objects inside the same array into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var arrObj = [{a:1, b:2},{c:3, d:4},{e:5, f:6}];
```

how can i merge this into one obj?

```
//mergedObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6}
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

If your environment supports [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), then you can do the same in a succinct way like this

```js
const arrObj = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3, d: 4}, {e: 5, f: 6}];

console.log(arrObj.reduce(function(result, current) {
  return Object.assign(result, current);
}, {}));

// If you prefer arrow functions, you can make it a one-liner ;-)
console.log(arrObj.reduce(((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c)), {}));

// Thanks Spen from the comments. You can use the spread operator with assign
console.log(Object.assign({}, ...arrObj));
```

---

ES5 solution:

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this

```
var resultObject = arrObj.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
    for(var key in currentObject) {
        if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[key] = currentObject[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(resultObject);
# { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 }
```

This solution, simply gathers all the keys and their values in every object in the `result`, which is finally returned to us as the result.

This check

```
if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
```

is necessary to make sure that we are not including all the inherited enumerable properties in the result.

Comment: We can avoid using reduce completely by invoking `Object.assign` with `apply`.

`Object.assign.apply( null, objects );`

Comment: Or, use the spread operator: `Object.assign( ...arrObj )`

Comment: @Spen Thanks. I have included your suggestion as well in the answer.

Comment: @Spen FYI, `Object.assign(...arrObj)` mutates the first element of the array. So, should be: `Object.assign({}, ...arrObj)`

Comment: Object.assign({}, [{one: 1},{two: 2}, {three:3}]) ,, i find this helpful, and very works on me.

Answer (score 25):

You could use `reduce` for an elegant solution:

```
arrObj.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    for (var key in x) acc[key] = x[key];
    return acc;
}, {});
```

See [MDN docs for `reduce` for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).