# How to merge an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array of object.

```
Objs[0] = {Name : "ABC"};
Objs[1] = {Roll : 123}
```

I want to merge both, It will be like

```
Objs {
   Name : "ABC",
   Roll : 123
}
```

Any way to I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple objects inside the same array into one object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538349/merge-multiple-objects-inside-the-same-array-into-one-object)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically you need each in array, n object merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method.

```js
var Objs = [{
  Name: "ABC"
}, {
  Roll: 123
}];

console.log(
  Object.assign.apply(null, [{}].concat(Objs))
)
```

---

Or you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) instead of [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

```js
var Objs = [{
  Name: "ABC"
}, {
  Roll: 123
}];

console.log(
  Object.assign({}, ...Objs)
)
```

Comment: @David : use polyfill : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code.

```
var jsonObj = {};

$.each(Objs, function(index) {

    $.each(Objs[index], function(key, value) {
        jsonObj[key] = value;

    });
});
```