# Transform an array of objects into a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I am trying to combine an array of object into one object that merges the values of all of the like properties.

```js
objArray = [{
  foo: ["f", "b"],
  bar: ["e"]
}, {
  foo: ["a", "c"],
  bar: ["a", "c"]
}, {
  foo: ["f", "b"],
  bar: ["z"]
}];
const newObj = {
  foo: [],
  bar: []
};
objArray.forEach((obj) => {
  newObj.foo.push(...obj.foo);
  newObj.bar.push(...obj.bar);
});
console.log(newObj);
```

I am getting the desired output with the above code. Is using a forEach loop like above the best way to achieve what I am setting out to do? Ideally I don't want to have to specify the properties to merge, I would like the code to merge identical property names automatically.

**Edit:**

I need to support IE11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple objects inside the same array into one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538349/merge-multiple-objects-inside-the-same-array-into-one-object)

Comment: Not a dupe @Nisarg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use a nested reduce() of `Object#entries()` to iterate properties without needing to hard code specific property names anywhere

```js
objArray = [{
  foo: ["f", "b"],
  bar: ["e"]
}, {
  foo: ["a", "c"],
  bar: ["a", "c"]
}, {
  foo: ["f", "b"],
  bar: ["z"]
}];

const res= objArray.reduce((acc,c)=>{
   return Object.entries(c).reduce((a,[k,v])=>{
       a[k] = (a[k] || []).concat(v)
       return a
   },acc)
},{})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I'm realizing that I cannot use `Object.entries`. Are you able to add a solution without it?

Comment: Could add polyfill, it's not much code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

You could take the entries of the objects for an arbitrary count of keys and values.

```js
var data = [{ foo: ["f", "b"], bar: ["e"] }, { foo: ["a", "c"], bar: ["a", "c"] }, { foo: ["f", "b"], bar: ["z"] }],
    merged = data.reduce((r, o) => 
        Object.entries(o).reduce((s, [k, v]) =>
            Object.assign(s, { [k]: (s[k] || []).concat(v) }), r), {});
        
console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use Object.keys and two loops using forEach

1. First loop with forEach will handle each object
2. Second loop with Object.keys will handle each object keys and push to new Array with keys
3. Use Object.hasOwnProperty to key value in newObj with original array object properties

```js
objArray = [
  {
    foo: ["f", "b"],
    bar: ["e"],
    zoo: ["z"]
  },
  {
    foo: ["a", "c"],
    bar: ["a", "c"]
  },
  {
    foo: ["f", "b"],
    bar: ["z"]
  }
];
const newObj = {
  foo: [],
  bar: []
};
objArray.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(v => {
    if (newObj.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
      newObj[v].push(obj[v]);
    }
  });
});
console.log(newObj);
```

codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MqOpWm?editors=1010

Comment: What if there is an object in the array that look like `{
  foo: ["f", "b"],
  bar: ["z"],
  zoo: ["123"]
}`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, updated my answer with a check of Object.hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

Using forEach as you, but `for in` inside.

```js
var objArray = [{foo: ["f", "b"],bar: ["e"]},{foo: ["a", "c"],bar:["a", "c"]},{foo: ["f", "b"],bar: ["z"]}];

var newObj = {};

objArray.forEach(o => {
  for (p in o) {
    if (!(p in newObj)) {
      newObj[p] = [];
    }
    newObj[p] = [...newObj[p], ...o[p]];
  }
});

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking @charlietfl answer and editing it for IE (using `Object.keys` instead of `Object.entries`)

```js
objArray = [{
  foo: ["f", "b"],
  bar: ["e"]
}, {
  foo: ["a", "c"],
  bar: ["a", "c"]
}, {
  foo: ["f", "b"],
  bar: ["z"]
}];

const res = objArray.reduce((acc, c) => {
  return Object.keys(c).reduce((a, k) => {
    let v = c[k];
    a[k] = (a[k] || []).concat(v);
    return a;
  }, acc);
}, {});

console.log(res)
```