# How to avoid overwrite in JavaScript object array merging

Tags: react-native

I am new to the react native, How to Merge two java script object array.
Using `object.assign()` , it works  but it will overwrite the same field.

```
Array1 = {
  '2018-12-15': { marked:true, dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-16': { marked:true, dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-17': { marked:true, dotColor:'red' },
}

Array2 = {
  '2018-12-15': { marked:true, dotColor:'green' },
  '2018-12-26': { marked:true, dotColor:'green' },
  '2018-12-27': { marked:true, dotColor:'green' },
}
```

Output should be:

```
Result = {
  '2018-12-15': { marked:true, dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-16': { marked:true, dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-17': { marked:true, dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-15': { marked:true, dotColor:'green' },
  '2018-12-26': { marked:true, dotColor:'green' },
  '2018-12-27': { marked:true, dotColor:'green' },
 }
```

Comment: Hey it seems like maybe you tagged this as `react-native` on accident. This problem would get better assistance tagged as `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible because an object cannot have a duplicate property. Think about it, if your object has two properties called `2018-12-15`:

```
const result = {
  '2018-12-15': value,
  '2018-12-15': value2,
}
```

how could you access them both? `result['2018-12-15']` now has a totally ambiguous value and it's for that reason that javascript objects cannot have duplicate keys.

If you want to merge the objects you could do something simple like this:

```
const result = { ...Array2, ...Array1 }
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  '2018-12-15'. : { marked:true,dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-16'. : { marked:true,dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-17'. : { marked:true,dotColor:'red' },
  '2018-12-26'. : { marked:true,dotColor:'green' },
  '2018-12-27'. : { Bmarked:true,dotColor:'green' },
}
```

This is called [object spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), basically I "unpackaged" the two initial objects and wrapped them in brackets to create one new object. The final properties are determined based on which object is placed last, so

```
const result = { ...Array1, ...Array2 }
```

will output:

```
{
  '2018-12-15': {marked: true, dotColor: "green"},
  '2018-12-16': {marked: true, dotColor: "red"},
  '2018-12-17': {marked: true, dotColor: "red"},
  '2018-12-26': {marked: true, dotColor: "green"},
  '2018-12-27': {marked: true, dotColor: "green"}
}
```

If you want even greater control of how objects are merged you can [use the built in `reduce` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27538363/8378419)