# How to insert an array of json into a single json

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an array of json -

```
var finalResponse2 = [
{Transaction Amount: {type: "number"}},
{UTR number: {type: "string"}}
]
```

And I want to convert it like this

```
responses : [
{
Transaction Amount: {type: "number"},
UTR number: {type: "string"}
}]
```

I have written the code like -

```
     var innerField1 =  {};
      var innerField2 = {};
      for (var l=0 ; l < this.finalResponse2.length ; l++){

        let key1 = Object.keys(this.finalResponse2[l])[0]
       let value1 = Object.values(this.finalResponse2[l])[0]
       let key2  = Object.keys(value1)[0]
       let value2 =  Object.values(value1)[0]


       innerField1[key2] = value2 
       key1[key2] = value2

       key1.key2 = value2
        fields['responses'].key1.key1[key2] = value2
      }

    }
```

> But I am getting error - 
>   Cannot create property 'type' on string 'Transaction Amount'

Comment: First, that is not JSON and second, I doubt that you really have defined the object in your example that way since it is invalid. Third: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538349/merge-multiple-objects-inside-the-same-array-into-one-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` function and spread operator `...` to get the desired result:

```js
let finalResponse2 = [
 {"Transaction Amount": {type: "number"}},
 {"UTR number": {type: "string"}}
];

let result = [Object.assign({}, ...finalResponse2)];
console.log(result);
```