# How do i change the object values to Array in angular 8?

Tags: jquery, arrays, angular

I have set of object values, i need them to be change to array .

```
 var data =[
  {
    "project": "Sciera Internal Application",
    "hours": {
      "DATA SCIENCE": 3270,
      "DEVELOPMENT": 2895,
      "QUALITY ENGINEERING": 780,
      "OPERATION": 33175,
      "MARKET": 3935,
      "DATA": 15750
    }
  },
  {
    "project": "RealWatch",
    "hours": {
      "OPERATION": 2490,
      "DATA SCIENCE": 810,
      "QUALITY ENGINEERING": 26045,
      "DATA ": 21340
    }
  },
 ]
```

i need them to be changed like array of array and colon to be replace by comma.

```
 data: [ ["DATA SCIENCE",3270],["DEVELOPMENT",7.36],["QUALITY ENGINEERING",7.02],["OPERATION",5.11],["MARKET",6.1],["DATA",2.95]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner solution: [Merge all `data.hours` into one object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27538363/9183405), then use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key value pair as a comma separated array.

```js
var data = [{
    "project": "Sciera Internal Application",
    "hours": {
      "DATA SCIENCE": 3270,
      "DEVELOPMENT": 2895,
      "QUALITY ENGINEERING": 780,
      "OPERATION": 33175,
      "MARKET": 3935,
      "DATA": 15750
    }
  },
  {
    "project": "RealWatch",
    "hours": {
      "OPERATION": 2490,
      "DATA SCIENCE": 810,
      "QUALITY ENGINEERING": 26045,
      "DATA": 21340
    }
  },
]

const results = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...data.map(datum => datum.hours)));
console.log(results)
```